# Yii DAO implementation.

Tags: yii

If I only use DAO to save data in Yii , can I use the rules function of the model ? Of course I would not be declaring AR instance . Can I still validate using rules function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new model class extending CModel.

Create the rules method as normal.

You can then do

```
$model = new MyModel();
$model->myAttribute = 'value';

if ($model->validate())
{
    Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->update(
            'MyTable',
            array('myAttribute' => $model->myAttribute),
            'key=:id',
            array(':id' => 'key')
        );
}
```

Comment: But doesn't that defeat the purpose of performance tuning ? The definitive guide to yii states "Although Active Record is good at modelling data in an OOP fashion, it actually degrades performance due to the fact that it needs to create one or several objects to represent each row of query result. " 
However in my application I have to query a single user's records at a time , the records are split in 9 tables or so . So I would be declaring as many model instances . If I am validating using the model instance why not save as well ?

Comment: My example doesn't use Active Record. It uses the CModel class which has the validation functions you're asking for.

Comment: So your declaration of MyModel() class  extends CModel instead of CActiveRecord ?  The usage here does not seem to be very different from AR apart from saving it using createCommand ? How is AR different then ?

Comment: Yes, MyModel() extends CModel, this allows me to use the validation functions without the overhead of AR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use without problems.

Here are some links that can help you:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao
- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25825-dao-vs-activerecord-methods/
- http://www.sheldmandu.com/php/php-mvc-frameworks/yii-dao-vs-active-record-performance

Comment: Can you guide me to an example/documentation ? I have used validation rules using AR instances but never when using DAO . Thanks !!

Comment: Okay , I was just working on a strategy before I start out with the actual coding . I read up on the Definitive guide to yii that for data intensive applications AR should be avoided due to performance issues . Since I am pretty much an amateur with yii I wanted to be sure I can do the necessary validations if I shift to DAO from AR without sweating too much in setting up validation conditions myself .I have really no idea on how to validate using rules apart from in AR .

Comment: I understand.

I have not done any examples here, but leave some interesting links for your reference.